# Uploading a file to GraphQL using Apollo Client

Tags: android, react-native, graphql, apollo-client, react-native-fs

I am currently trying to upload a file (an image from RNCamera) from a react native android app to a GraphQL backend. However, the backend always returns **status code 400**.

So far, I have tried using another query that only requires a string (instead of the $file argument) and that worked. So the Apollo Client seems to be set up correctly. I have also tried sending files to the backend using curl. That worked fine as well.

```
import { API_URL } from 'src/utils/config';    
import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache, ApolloLink, gql } from '@apollo/client';
import { createUploadLink } from 'apollo-upload-client';
import { UPLOAD_PICTURE } from 'src/utils/query';

var RNFS = require('react-native-fs');

// Instantiate required constructor fields
const cache = new InMemoryCache();
const link = ApolloLink.from([
  createUploadLink({
    uri: API_URL
  })
]);

const client = new ApolloClient({
  // Provide required constructor fields
  cache: cache,
  link: link
});
```

Executing the mutation:

```
// read the image that was saved as a file
const file = {
    file: await RNFS.readFile(action.picture.uri, 'base64')
  };

// send the file to the backend
 client
    .mutate({
      mutation: gql(UPLOAD_PICTURE),
      variables: file
    })
```

From src/utils/query:

```
export const UPLOAD_PICTURE = `
mutation ($file: Upload!){
  uploadFile(file: $file)
}
`;
```

The GraphQL schema in the backend:

```
type File {
    uri: String!
    filename: String!
    mimetype: String!
    encoding: String!
  }

//...

type Mutation {
  //...
  uploadFile(file: Upload!): File
}
```

Comment: 1st - test backend with postman, 2nd, send a file, not content/stream etc ... compare network request with postman

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. A tool that really helped me while testing was the [React Native Debugger](https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger) with the "Network Inspect" option enabled. I found a solution for my problem (see below).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem. The `file` has to be of type `ReactNativeFile`  (more info [here](https://github.com/jaydenseric/apollo-upload-client#class-reactnativefile)). The code now looks like this:

```
...    
const file = new ReactNativeFile({
        uri: action.picture.uri,
        name: 'name.jpg',
        type: 'image/jpeg'
    });
...
```

There was also a [bug](https://github.com/jaydenseric/apollo-upload-client/issues/188) with React Native 0.62+ that messes up the configuration for multiform requests. It can be fixed by commenting out **line 43** in `android/app/src/debug/java/com/maxyride/app/drivers/ReactNativeFlipper.java`:

```
//builder.addNetworkInterceptor(new FlipperOkhttpInterceptor(networkFlipperPlugin));
```