# How nestjs graphql FileUpload accept ReactNativeFile()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, graphql, nestjs

I am trying to upload a image from my react native app. As far as I know, I need to use class/package ReactNativeFile() with a uri then append the file to the graphql varible. The following is a minimum reproduce example:

The way that I upload file:

```
function generateRNFile(uri, name) {
  return uri ? new ReactNativeFile({
    uri,
    type: mime.lookup(uri) || 'image',
    name,
  }) : null;
}

 async function onUploadPress() {
  status && setStatus(null);
  const file = generateRNFile(image, `picture-${Date.now()}`);
  try {
  await uploadImage({
      variables: { image: file },
    });
    setStatus('Uploaded')
  } catch (e) {
    setStatus('Error')
  }
}
```

This graphql is tested through playground which I am sure that there is no bug.

However, I am geting such error

```
"message": "Variable \"$file\" got invalid value { uri: \"file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/xxxx/Library/Caches/ExponentExperienceData/xxx.jpg\", name: \"picture-xxx\", type: \"image/jpeg\" }; Upload value invalid.",
```

Is there anyone that could help me to figure out the reason?
Much Thanks

Edit:

The input type that I am using is from:

```
import { FileUpload } from 'graphql-upload';
```

And I just tried to console.log the file that I upload successfully from my backend.

```
{
  filename: 'Screenshot 2023-04-04 015848.png',
  mimetype: 'image/png',
  encoding: '7bit',
  createReadStream: [Function: createReadStream]
}
```

I know I current pass the type

```
new ReactNativeFile({
    uri,
    type: mime.lookup(uri) || 'image',
    name,
  })
```

which looks like:

{
uri: "file://xxxx",
name: "xxxx",
type: "image/jpeg"
}

Here is the the type that type that I suppose to pass in
How I can I get the type from react native

My typing is very similar to the post:
[Uploading a file to GraphQL using Apollo Client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63410044/uploading-a-file-to-graphql-using-apollo-client)

However ReactNativeFile doesn't solve my problem

Comment: GraphQL is complaining that your `image` variable doesn't match the  shape of the `input type` defined for the `uploadImage` mutation. Please share the definition of your `uploadImage` mutation and the `image` *input type* it expects.

Comment: @MichelFloyd Please check my edit. appreciate for you help!

Comment: `import { FileUpload }…` is not defining a GraphQL *input type*. If you have introspection turned on use GraphiQL or Apollo Sutdio to look at the `uploadImage` mutation then further look at the type it expects.